# Using SQL "Like" with a variable

Tags: sql, variables

I am trying to add a variable to part of a select in SQL. However, this appears to fail.

```
set @search = '''%fishing%'' OR book_text like ''%seaside%'' AND book_text like  ''%docks%'''

print @search

select * 
from constituency 
where book_text like @search

select * 
from constituency 
where book_text like '%fishing%' 
   or book_text like '%seaside%' 
  and book_text like '%docks%'
```

The first select using the `@search` variable does not return any rows, however, the second manual search returns the correct no of rows the print of the `@search` variable shows

```
'%fishing%' or book_text like '%seaside%' and book_text like  '%docks%'
```

Comment: I think you may need to use dynamic sql to build the query at run time. Right now the search parameter is considered the string to match if you put in the where clause directly. 
So the first query looks like this:
select * 
from constituency 
where book_text like '%fishing%' or book_text like '%seaside%' and book_text like  '%docks%''

book_text is being compared with "%fishing%' or book_text like '%seaside%' and book_text like  '%docks%'"

Comment: Your syntax is product specific, you should TAG your RDBMS. I'd be surprised if you actually had book_text with the value *''%fishing%'' OR book_text like ''%seaside%'' AND book_text like  ''%docks%''* because that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL is needed. I've tested below code snippet in SQL Server. It works.

```
begin
declare @search varchar(max);
declare @query_str varchar(max);
set @search = '''%fishing%'' OR book_text like ''%seaside%'' AND book_text like  ''%docks%'''

select @query_str = 'select * 
from constituency 
where book_text like' + @search;

exec(@query_str);

end;
```